# Rotate a matrix by 90 degrees

Tags: python, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Background

I am solving a standard [LeetCode Question 48](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-image/). I know there are many solutions out there but I am trying to solve the question with an approach that makes sense to me. I am basically trying to rotate a matrix 90 degrees. I am trying to swap each value of each layer of the square matrix.

Here is my code:

```
def rotate_image(matrix):
    top = 0
    bottom = len(matrix)
    left = 0
    right = len(matrix[0])
    total_layers = round(bottom / 2)

    for i in range(0, total_layers):

        for j in range(left, right - 1):
            top_left = matrix[top][j]
            top_right = matrix[j][right - 1]
            bottom_right = matrix[bottom - 1][right - (j + 1)]
            bottom_left = matrix[bottom - (1+j)][left]
            matrix[top][j] = bottom_left
            matrix[j][right - 1] = top_left
            matrix[bottom - 1][right - (j + 1)] = top_right
            matrix[bottom - (1 + j)][left] = bottom_right
        top += 1
        left += 1
        right -= 1
        bottom -= 1
    print(matrix)
```

For some reason, my code is passing most cases but when I try the following case

```
print(rotate_image([[5, 1, 9, 11], [2, 4, 8, 10], [13, 3, 6, 7], [15, 14, 12, 16]]))
```

it fails. I have spent 2 hours trying to debug it and I may be over looking something but not sure what it is exactly.

I would love some feedback.

Comment: Perform your algorithm for a small failing example with pen and paper. compare after each step if the partial result does fit what you expect for the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are having indexing issue. Let's examine part of your code:

```
for j in range(left, right - 1):
    top_left = matrix[top][j]
    top_right = matrix[j][right - 1]
    bottom_right = matrix[bottom - 1][right - (j + 1)]
```

Consider what happens when `j` takes value `right-2`.  You will extract an entry from the column `right - (j+1) = right - (right-2+1)=1`. That is regardless of which layer you are in, you will extract from the `1`-th column.  You need to adjust back to the starting point of the layer, that is rather than `right - (j+1)`-th column, you need to access `left + right - (j+1)`-th column.  Furthermore, notice that `left + right` is actually a constant, it is equal to the length of the matrix. You can take advantage of the negative indexing in Python and access `-(j+1)`-th column instead.

Also, we are already told that it is a square matrix, so `top` and `left` is always the same and `bottom` and `right` are always equal.

Here is a code that works performing the correction that I mentioned above:

```
def rotate(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify matrix in-place instead.
    """
    top = 0
    bottom = len(matrix)
    total_layers = round(bottom / 2)

    for i in range(0, total_layers):
        for j in range(top, bottom - 1):
            top_left = matrix[top][j]
            top_right = matrix[j][bottom - 1]
            bottom_right = matrix[bottom - 1][ - (j + 1)]
            bottom_left = matrix[- (1+j)][top]
            matrix[top][j] = bottom_left
            matrix[j][bottom-1] = top_left 
            matrix[bottom - 1][- (j + 1)] = top_right
            matrix[- (1 + j)][top] = bottom_right
        top += 1
        bottom -= 1
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that attempts to help the OP with their question about their code.

Answer (score 4):

I can provide you an alternative clean approach to rotate a square matrix 90 degree.

step 1: swap the element across diagonal.
step 2: horizontally mirror image the elements

you got your rotated matrix.

Also you may play around horizontal vs vertical mirror image, based on in which direction you need to rotate the matrix.

e.g.

[image]

you got your 90° rotated matrix

Answer (score 0):

The next approach chooses left upper quarter of matrix, stores an element from this quarter and rearranges corresponding elements from other quarters in cyclic manner

```
def rotate_image(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(0, (n + 1) // 2):
        for j in range(0, n // 2):
            storage = matrix[i][j]
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[n - j - 1][i]
            matrix[n - j - 1][i] = matrix[n - i - 1][n - j - 1]
            matrix[n - i - 1][n - j - 1] = matrix[j][n - i - 1]
            matrix[j][n - i - 1] = storage
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[i])

mt = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

rotate_image(mt)
print()

mt = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21,22, 23,24,25]]

rotate_image(mt)

[13, 9, 5, 1]
[14, 10, 6, 2]
[15, 11, 7, 3]
[16, 12, 8, 4]

[21, 16, 11, 6, 1]
[22, 17, 12, 7, 2]
[23, 18, 13, 8, 3]
[24, 19, 14, 9, 4]
[25, 20, 15, 10, 5]
```